# How to animate a copy of the div from the current position to the top right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to animate a div from the current position to the top left , How can I do that

the CSS and HTML code looks something like this

```css
.addProducts {
  Height:700px;
  width:70%;
  background-color:skyblue;     
}
.productHolder{
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  width:50%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:yellow;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
}
.item{
  width:150px;
  left:2px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="addProducts">
  <div class="productHolder">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically I have to clone the current div (.item) and append it to the top right corner of the div `.addProducts`  and so on like the the `.items` should be replicated one after other just like they are right now but on the other div.

Also I have to show it in animation

I have created a fiddle to make things faster for you

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d5w7sjr/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

Use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select `.productHolder`

Apply a [`Node.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event handler to the selected [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node).

Check if the [clicked element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) has the class `item`.

Use [`Node.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to clone the node and it's contents

Use [`Element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) to apply the relevant styles

Use [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to prepend the cloned element into `.add-products`

And you're done!

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/5n485zdu/2/))

```
document.querySelector('.productHolder').onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target.className === 'item') {
        var clone = e.target.cloneNode(true);
        clone.style.float = 'right';
        clone.style.clear = 'both';
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: @humblerumble can you suggest any link I can read this I have no Idea of these functions

Answer (score 1):

Cloning current div to the next container, try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/9d5w7sjr/4/).

```
$('.productHolder .item').on('click',function(){   
    var cloneX = $(this).remove().addClass('new').clone();
    $(cloneX).appendTo('.productHolder2')   
    $('.new').animate({
         opacity: 0.25 //use more parameter for effect
    }, 1000)
});
```