# Animate an element from any position to the top right corner

Tags: css, css-animations

**Disclaimer:** This question is similar to [How to animate a copy of the div from the current position to the top right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658763/how-to-animate-a-copy-of-the-div-from-the-current-position-to-the-top-right), however, in the solution, the animation consists of blending in the moved item, where I need to animate the movement to the new position.

**What I tried:** The button jumps to the top right corner, but I need it to smoothly animate there.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('moveToTopRight')
});
```

```css
@keyframes moveToTopRight {
  from {
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  to {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}

.moveToTopRight {
  animation: moveToTopRight 2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>x</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing right from 100% to 0%?
And you're changing the position attribute in your keyframe. Why?

Comment: The element which I want to animate is an inline element somewhere on a website, so it needs `position:fixed` to be positioned in the corner. When I go from 100% to 0% it does animate, however, the starting point is wrong and thereby the user does not get the desired feedback, that the very element he clicked moves away